# JS check if nested array has the same value as another array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Hi I want to check if "arr" includes one of the sub arrays of "arrNested" and get a boolean value.
I want something like `arrNested.includes(arr)` that works for nested arrays
`console.log(arrNested.includes(arr))` returns false and I don't know why

```
let arr = [1,2,3]
let arrNested = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
]
```

Comment: What is preventing you from writing this?

Comment: Does `[1, 2, 3] == [3, 2, 1]`?

Comment: _“`console.log(arrNested.includes(arr))` returns `false` and I don’t know why”_ — [duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+includes+with+nested+array+returns+false) of [Why can't I use Array#includes for a nested array?](/q/48088657/4642212).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

If the order matters, use:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3]
let arrNested = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
]

function includes(a, b) {
  return a.some(e => e.toString() == b.toString());
}
console.log(includes(arrNested, arr));
```

If the order *does not* matter, first sort, then compare:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3]
let arrNested = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
]

function includes(a, b) {
  var s = b.sort().toString();
  return a.some(e => e.sort().toString() == s);
}
console.log(includes(arrNested, arr));
```